# Disable button works first time but not after pressed once, how can I fix this?

Tags: jquery

HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inputGroupSelect02").change(function() {
    var str = "";
    if ($("#inputGroupSelect02 option:selected").val() == '') {

      $('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {

      $('#button').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect02">
    <option selected>Choose how many columns you need</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
  </select>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect02">Columns</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect03">
    <option selected>Choose how many rows you need</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
  </select>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect03">Rows</label>
  </div>

</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="createTable()" id="button" disabled="disabled"> Insert  </button>
```

The function works in the beginning, the button is disabled until I choose the option. But as soon as I press INSERT and the table is inserted, the button doesn't become Disabled anymore until I refresh the page.
How could I fix this? Thank you!

UPDATE WITH WHAT TABLE DO.

```
function createTable(){

 $('#myTable').empty();

 var rn = $('#inputGroupSelect03').val();

 var cn = $('#inputGroupSelect02').val();

 for(var r=0;r<parseInt(rn,10);r++){
 var x=document.getElementById('myTable').insertRow(r);
 for(var c=0;c<parseInt(cn,10);c++)  {

 var y=  x.insertCell(c);
 y.innerHTML="<img src='SOURCE IMG HERE' alt='hello'/>";
 $("#myTable tr td").rotatable({snap:true }); $("#myTable tr td ").draggable({

  appendTo: "#droppable",
  containment: ".chart-area",

  cancel:false,
  start: function(event, ui) {
    c.tr = this;
    c.helper = ui.helper;

  }
});

 jQuery('#inputGroupSelect03').get(0).selectedIndex = 0; 
 jQuery('#inputGroupSelect02').get(0).selectedIndex = 0; 


  }
 }
 }
```

I have updated the question with the "table code and what it does" since I've been asked.

Comment: What does `createTable` do? Maybe thats whats breaking it?

Comment: Well the val() is no longer == ' ' after you select an option. You need to check to see if table is built not if option is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are using jQuery never ever use an onevent attribute:

   <button <del>onclick='fnc()'</del>>

   ```
   // Use this instead 
   $('#button').on('click', function() {createTable()});
   ```
2. On the first `<option>`  add `value=""` to each:

   ```
   <option selected value=''>Choose how many columns you need</option>
   <option selected value=''>Choose how many rows you need</option>
   ```
3. Use the following control statement so that the button will only be enabled if **both `<select>` have a value***:

   ```
   if ($("#inputGroupSelect02").val() === '' || $("#inputGroupSelect03").val() === '') {...
   ```
4. jQuery considers a HTML attribute a property once it's established so use this:

   ```
   $('#button').prop('disabled', false);
   ```

   <sup>*Also don't use the selected `<option>`</sup> <sup>to get a value target the</sup> <sup>`<select>` (ex. `$('select').val()`)</sup>

---

### Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#button').on('click', function(e) {
    var rows = Number($("#inputGroupSelect02").val());
    var cols = Number($("#inputGroupSelect03").val());

    createTable(rows, cols);
    $(".custom-select").val('');
    $('#button').attr('disabled', true);
  });

  $(".custom-select").on('change', function() {

    if ($("#inputGroupSelect02").val() === '' || $("#inputGroupSelect03").val() === '') {

      $('#button').attr('disabled', true);

    } else {

      $('#button').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});

function createTable(rows, cols) {
  var T = $('.table')[0];
  var tB = T.tBodies[0];
  var rQTY = rows;
  var cQTY = cols;

  for (let r = 0; r < rQTY; r++) {
    var R = T.insertRow();
    for (let c = 0; c < cQTY; c++) {
      var C = R.insertCell();
      C.textContent = 'TD';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<main class='container'>
  <section class='row'>
    <form lass="form-inline col-sm-12">
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label class="input-group-text input-group col-sm-6" for="inputGroupSelect02">Rows</label>
        <select id="inputGroupSelect02" class="custom-select col-sm-6">
          <option selected value=''>Choose how many rows you need</option>
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
          <option value="3">Three</option>
          <option value="4">Four</option>
          <option value="5">Five</option>
          <option value="6">Six</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label class="input-group-text input-group col-sm-6" for="inputGroupSelect03">Columns</label>
        <select id="inputGroupSelect03" class="custom-select col-sm-6">
          <option selected value=''>Choose how many columns you need</option>
          <option value="1">One</option>
          <option value="2">Two</option>
          <option value="3">Three</option>
          <option value="4">Four</option>
          <option value="5">Five</option>
          <option value="6">Six</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>

      <button id="button" class="btn btn-success float-right" type="button" disabled>Insert</button>
    </form>
  </section>
  <hr>
  <section class='row'>
    <figure class='table-responsive'>
      <table class='table table-hover'>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </figure>

  </section>
</main>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have checked the code a few times, made sure I have copied correctly, but unfortunately it still not solves the problem, the Insert button becomes enabled again after I the first event.

Comment: You want it disabled after click? I had it disabled if one of the selects doesn't have a value. You want button to be disabled after every click to avoid double clicking?

Comment: I want it disabled if there is no option selected. It works first event, the button is disabled, I choose the value, the button becomes enabled, I pressed, the table is built and the options go back to the initial stage (empty) when the button should be disabled again until there will be options selected again, and so on.

Comment: The second edit didn't work, but with your first answer and with some added code to the table it's working. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button, the buttons already become enabled. To disable it, the value of the input needs to become blank.

To fix that, just add a `.click` event handler for the button so that when you click the button, it becomes disabled.

**Note:** You could also add all the stuff inside the `.click` into the `createTable` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inputGroupSelect02").change(function() {
    var str = "";
    if ($("#inputGroupSelect02 option:selected").val() == '') {
      $('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('#button').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
  
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});

function createTable() {
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect02">
    <option selected>Choose how many columns you need</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
  </select>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect02">Columns</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect03">
    <option selected>Choose how many rows you need</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
  </select>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect03">Rows</label>
  </div>

</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="createTable()" id="button" disabled="disabled"> Insert  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some change in your html code like this :

```
 <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect02">
    <option value='' selected>Choose how many columns you need</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
  </select>
```

I've add a value on the first option to get the JS code works :

```
  $("#inputGroupSelect02, #inputGroupSelect03").change(function() {
    var str = "";
    if ($(this).find('option:selected').val() == '') {
      $('#button').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('#button').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
```

You can also use `prop('disabled', true)`

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a69o52gk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Its simply a matter of handling the event better. I suggest resetting the val to '' once you have built the table then disable the button again.

```
 function buildTable(){
    //build table do your thing...
    $('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#inputGroupSelect02 option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
}
```

Comment: the table is already built, I've have updated the question with the table code. Thank you!

Comment: youre welcome! Glad I could help. Please check as answer if this got you there. :-)